# Adjusting video src to URL parameter

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to set the src to my video according to the URL parameter (after the ?)
Here's what I've got so far:

```html
<video></video>
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("video").src="###";
```

I need help with setting the ### src value to the correct value like so:
**realistic example**

> *https://website.com/player?@#$%*
>
> ```js
> src="https://areallylongaddress.com/videosourcefolder/@#$%";
> ```

**simpler example**

> *https://website.com/player?intro_video*
>
> ```js
> src="https://areallylongaddress.com/videosourcefolder/intro_video";
> ```

essentially, a strip of code that sets the video src to a fixed string value (areallylongaddress.com), then adds the url parameter to the end

Comment: so, what is the help you require?

Comment: "sets the video src to a fixed string value ... then adds the url parameter to the end"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly u want to set the src of the video to the url parameter(query string).
Usually query strings are link this - "https://website.com/player?srcName=intro_video" So all u need to do is

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
// querySting = ?srcName=intro_video
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const src_name = urlParams.get('src_name');
console.log(src_name);
//prints "intro_video"
document.getElementsByTagName("video").src=src_name;
```

Edit -

```js
      //main Html form where u go to https://website.com/player?folders/vkxq2f.mp4 page
    let vid_URL = "https://files.catbox.moe/vkxq2f.mp4";
    let vid_name = vid_URL.split('/').at(-1);
    console.log(vid_name);
    //here you do something like onclick(window.href=`https://website.com/player?video=${vid_name}`)

    //Then in player.html
    document.getElementsByTagName("video").src = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('video');
```

Comment: From the URL itself you will get the name of the video u just prepend the "src="https://areallylongaddress.com/videosourcefolder" part to the src_name

Comment: OK heres something you can try, I edited the answer

Comment: any chance you could try creating an example html file with this code for me? I can't seem to get it working...